# How to understand algebraic independence of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

Now we have a vector $p=(p_1,\cdots,p_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. It is said that $p$ is algebraically independent if there does not exist a nonzero polynomial $h(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ with integer coefficients such that $h(p_1,\cdots,p_n)=0$. Moreover, it is said that the set of all these algebraically independent points form a dense set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am confused about the definition of algebraic independence for vectors. I have the following questions.

1. Can a linear function with nonzero coefficients be viewed as a specific nonzero polynomial function? For example, suppose $\lambda_1p_1+\cdots+\lambda_np_n=0$ holds, where $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are not all zero integers. Can we determine that $p$ is algebraically dependent?
2. If the anwser of 1 is "Yes", I think any $p$ with rational components can always be algebraically dependent if $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ are not all zero.
3. Consider another case that $p=(p_1^T,\cdots,p_n^T)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{nd}$, where $p_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $n>d$. If $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ are linearly dependent, is $p$ algebraically dependent? If the answer is "Yes", since $n>d$, $p$ is always algebraically dependent. Or should I focus on whether $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ are linearly dependent with all coefficients integers?

In fact, in the reference, an algebraically independent vector is called a generic point. Many authors characterize this property from a geometric perspective. For example, a generic point cannot be degenerate, i.e., $rank(p_1,\cdots,p_n)=d$, where $p_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Another example is that the set of generic points is dense, and its complement is of measure zero. However, if the answer of 3 is "Yes", it seems that a vector in $R^{nd}$ always cannot be generic. How can such points form a dense set?

I have been confused with this problem for a long time. Please try to answer me! Thank you!

Comment: Not following your point $2$.  Yes, a vector $p$ with all rational components is "algebraically dependent".  Is that the point you are making?  Also, what is the meaning of the superscript $^T$?

Comment: For (1) and (2) "yes" is right. I'd have to think through (3) to answer.

Comment: "T" means transpose. I just want to make it clear that whether linear dependence is a special case  of algebraic dependence. Moreover, if all vectors with rational components are algebraically dependent, it seems that algebraically dependent vectors will form a dense set. This is a contradiction with the fact that algebraically independent points form a dense set.

Comment: No contradiction. On the line the rationals are dense; so are the irrationals.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think you are right. But for the third question, if there exist not all zero integers $\lambda_i$, such that $\lambda_1p_1+\cdots+\lambda_np_n=0$, where $p_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Can we conclude that $p$ is algebraically dependent?

Comment: Anyone can help me ? Please...